# IndexedDb login function

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have been working with indexedDB for a few hours now. I am attempting to create a registration and login system. Registration has worked well but the following code for login doesn't work. The error comes at the first alert after onsuccess. Can anyone help me identify where the error is? Thanks.

```
function getUser(e) {

 var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
 var password = document.querySelector("#password").value;

 console.log("About to login "+email);

 var transaction = db.transaction(["users"]); //readonly
 var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("users");
 var request = objectStore.get(email);

 request.onerror = function(e) {
  alert("Unable to retrieve data from database!");
  return;
 };
 request.onsuccess = function(e) {
  alert(password " " + request.result.password);
  if(password != request.result.password) {
   alert("Could not log you in");
   return;
  } 
  console.log("You are logged in");

 };
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? I think request.result is empty? Because probably a cursor couldn't be found, is email the key for your user store? We need more info, for example how did you create your objectstore for users?

Comment: Thank you. I have just realized I used an automatic key generator instead of setting a keypath using email.

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDb in javascript: I got a solution.

This solution is working for me. you need to use the index to read the data by calling the `get()` method.

Code snippet:

```
function(e) {
    var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    var password = document.querySelector("#password").value;
    db = e.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction(["users"], "readonly");
    var store = tx.objectStore("users");
    // get the index from the Object Store
    const index = store.index('email');
    // query by indexes
    var query = index.get(key);
    query.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log(query.result)
        if(query.result)
        {
            if(password != query.result.password) {
                alert("In-correct Credentials... Please check and try 
                again!!!");
            }
         else{
             alert('success');                 
          }
       }
    };
};
```

For reference you may visit: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-indexeddb/